# Java - Connecting javascript to servlet in eclipse dynamic web project

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse

I am new to building dynamic web project. I have javascript as my front end. My query is how do i retrieve something from the database by clicking a button in the front end? How is javascript connected to servlet class to trigger an event in the backend?

Comment: The most common options are to trigger a traditional form submit and get a new page back, or make an Ajax request and update some part(s) of the current page with the result. Both options are http requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using servlet then you can use jsp (front end) as well to connect to your servlet, in jsp you need to write javascript code in `<head>` tag or by creating separate `.js` file then with help of `button` onclick function you will connect to your servlet by posting form 
Please read [this](http://crunchify.com/servlet-tutorial-getting-starting-with-jsp-servlet-example/)

Comment: *"you need to use jsp"* - You don't "need" to, there are other options. (Not that I'm saying jsp is a bad plan, just that it's not the only plan.)